# Measure code coverage of an executed shell script with kcov/shunit2

Tags: bash, shell, unit-testing, testing, kcov

Is it possible to measure the code coverage of an executed shell script instead of a sourced one?

I have a shell script with a couple of switches, options. I have added a few tests and I want to measure the test suite's coverage.

Sources:

[The script.](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vlajos/misspell_fixer/2d16e17c7901bd06e24d67f315e782f148d45d0b/misspell_fixer.sh)

[And its tests.](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vlajos/misspell_fixer/2d16e17c7901bd06e24d67f315e782f148d45d0b/test/tests.sh)

As you can see the `tests.sh` executes the shell script instead of calling its functions in the same shell. This way I couldn't get `kcov` to measure the coverage on the script. I was only able to measure the coverage on the file `tests.sh`.

Is it possible somehow to force `kcov` to measure the main script's coverage?

This command was the best I could achieve:

```
/usr/local/bin/kcov --debug=31 coverage/ test/tests.sh
```

And in the result I see only coverage report about `shunit2` and `tests.sh`, but in the debug output I see references to `misspell_fixer.sh` as well. So I'm suspicious that it could work.

Comment: Please take a look to LCOV.SH full BASH implementation of coverage... no need additional interpreters like RUBY or BINARY executable in your machine. Check coverage of BASH just with BASH https://github.com/javanile/lcov.sh

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please submit a bug report to the kcov issue tracker,

https://github.com/SimonKagstrom/kcov

it should support this as far as I can tell. (I'm the author of Kcov).

Comment: Thank you. I just created: https://github.com/SimonKagstrom/kcov/issues/45 I noticed that `set +x` can stop collecting data. Should I open a ticket for this as well?

Comment: kcov uses bash tracing to collect it's data, so that particular issue is probably difficult to get around. I can file a bug about it myself though, since other people are also likely to run into it at times.